# straight flush and royal flush for poker in python

Tags: python, poker

Here is some code I have so far for a poker game and I got the def main to show some of the hands but I can't figure out to get the straight flush and royal flush. Also how would I go about doing the high card?

The card number values 0-12 are one suit, 13-25 are the next, 26-38, and 39-51.

Also if anyone can tell me how I'd implement this PokerHand class into another def main window.

```
class PokerHand:

"""class for representing a poker hand"""

# Poker value of hands in increasing order so they can be compared
HIGH_CARD = 0
TWO_OF_A_KIND = 1
TWO_PAIRS = 2
THREE_OF_A_KIND = 3
STRAIGHT = 4
FLUSH = 5
FULL_HOUSE = 6
FOUR_OF_A_KIND = 7
STRAIGHT_FLUSH = 8

# hand names for printing the card names
HAND_NAMES = ('High Card', 'Two of a Kind', 'Two Pairs', 'Three of a Kind',
             'Straight', 'Flush', 'Full House', 'Four of a Kind',
             'Straight Flush')


#------------------------------------------------------------------

def __init__(self):

    """initialize empty hand"""

    self.cards = []

#------------------------------------------------------------------

def addCard(self, cardNumber):

    """add cardNumber to the hand"""

    self.cards.append(cardNumber)

#------------------------------------------------------------------

def evalHand(self):

    """determine the value of the hand and return a tuple; the
    first value in the tuple is an integer corresponding to the
    hand value using the constants HIGH_CARD, TWO_OF_A_KIND, etc.;
    the remaining values in the tuple depend on the type of hand
    and are described below to break ties based on the face values
    of the cards

    for HIGH_CARD, it is five values: the face values sorted in
    descending order

    for TWO_OF_A_KIND, it is four values: the face value for the
    pair, followed by the face values of the other cards in
    descending order

    for TWO_PAIRS, it is three values: the face value of the
    higher pair, the face value of the lower pair, followed by the
    face value of the other card

    for THREE_OF_A_KIND, it is three values: the face value of the
    three of a kind, followed by the face value of the other two
    cards in descending order

    for STRAIGHT, it is one value: the face value of the lowest
    card in the straight

    for FLUSH, it is five values: the face values sorted in
    descending order

    for FULL_HOUSE, it is two values: the face value of the three
    of a kind, followed by the face value of the pair

    for FOUR_OF_A_KIND, it is two values: the face value that
    there are four of followed by the face value that there is one
    of

    for STRAIGHT_FLUSH, it is one value: the face value of the
    lowest card in the straight"""

    faces = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for value in self.cards:
        face = value % 13
        faces[face] += 1

    suits = [0,0,0,0]
    for value in self.cards:
        suit = value // 13
        suits[suit] += 1

    if faces.count(2) == 1 and faces.count(1) == 3:
        return self.TWO_OF_A_KIND
    elif faces.count(2) == 2 and faces.count(1) == 1:
        return self.TWO_PAIRS
    elif faces.count(3) == 1 and faces.count(1) == 2:
        return self.THREE_OF_A_KIND
    elif faces.count(3) == 1 and faces.count(2) == 1:
        return self.FULL_HOUSE
    elif faces.count(4) == 1 and faces.count(1) == 1:
        return self.FOUR_OF_A_KIND
    elif faces.count(1) == 5:
        pos = faces.index(1)
        if faces[pos:pos+5] == [1,1,1,1,1] or faces[pos:pos+13] == [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]:
            return self.STRAIGHT
    if suits.count(5) == 1 and suits.count(1) == 0:
        return self.FLUSH
    if suits.count(5) == 1 and faces.count(1) == 5:
        pos = faces.index(1)
        if faces[pos:pos + 5] == [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] or faces[pos:pos + 13] == [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]:
            return self.STRAIGHT_FLUSH
    return self.STRAIGHT_FLUSH

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def main():
   hand = PokerHand()
   hand.addCard(9)
   hand.addCard(10)
   hand.addCard(8)
   hand.addCard(11)
   hand.addCard(7)

   r = hand.evalHand()
   print(r)
   print(PokerHand.HAND_NAMES[r])


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "implement this PokerHand class into another def main window"?

Comment: Rather than using the numbers to represent A234..JQKA234..., I would use AAAA22223333... that way, you eliminate the division by 13 (now it's just a shift), and it's easier to sort the hand by rank before checking each of the hand types.

Answer (score 1):

### Consider putting your hand conditionals in functions

This will help your code readability and also make it more testable.
E.g.

```py
def is_flush(suits):
    return suits.count(5) == 1
```

### Make sure lower value hands don't short circuit higher ones

If you rearrange the order of your hand conditionals, putting higher value tests first, you will catch the more specific case first and you won't accidentally return prematurely.

You could think of hands as being of two non-exclusive types: suit based and face based. Suit conditions are "flush" or "non-flush" so it might read well to flag this up front.
Then you have a face combos, some of which "intersect" with flush_flag to increase their value.

Or... you can keep your hand test ordered the way you have, it might be more optimal since you are testing for more frequent hands earlier. If you do this make sure your conditionals are "complete". I.e. if the hand is a two-of-a-kind you must also make sure it's not a two-pair or any of the other hands that contain two-of-a-kind. You are doing this with your faces.count(2) == 1 and faces.count(1) == 3. You need to follow the same "completeness" for STRAIGHT and FLUSH.

Comment: Yes, always test for hand types from the top down: first straight flush, then quads, then full house, etc., and after all those fail, you just have high cards. And before doing any of the tests, sort the hand by rank, and check for all-suits-equal. That will make the later tests much easier.